# Invoking activity from another project module

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have an application A which has two modules i.e. app and social

I want to invoke an activity in social from app. Isn't this possible ?

In app module when i try type in an activity that is in social, it doesn't resolve the name.

apps build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a999160.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(path: ':social', configuration: 'default')
}
```

socials's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.social"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the dependency of your module into app gradle like this :

```
implementation project(':social')
```

or else you can add "social" module manually:

1. Click on File
2. Go to project structure
3. Click on Dependencies ,you can see + sign at left bottom corner.
4. Select module Dependency
5. Select module to be added.

Now you can access all the members of module social in your main app. I hope this is what you were expecting.If you are still facing the problem then visit [Here](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio)

Answer (score 0):

update the `build.gradle` for the "social" module from

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

otherwise this is not possible (at least not, while not having both applications installed, already).

Comment: but martin my module needs to be a "project module" to hold activities right ? . If i apply the library plugin , would i still be able to host activities in the social module?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib you just have to reference the `Activity` class from within the `Manifest.xml` of the application module; in the library module's `Manifest.xml`, it will not be picked up.